# SwiftUI .popover dismiss won't work after List row being removed

Tags: swiftui, popover, mac-catalyst

I have a SwiftUI List with rows that contain a thumb. When clicked, this thumb opens a popover with a larger version of the image.

The problem I'm facing is that when a row, with its popover open, is removed from the list, the popover is left open and with no way of closing it, ending up with an unusable UI.

My goal would be to have the popover closed automatically when the row is removed from the list.

Following is a stripped version of the row's body. I'm using a Button because is more reliable than the onTapGesture event.

```
@State private var showPopover: Bool = false

var body: some View {

    Button(action: { self.showPopover = true }) {
        Image(systemName: "photo")
            .onDisappear { self.showPopover = false}
    }
    
    .popover(isPresented: $showPopover, arrowEdge: .leading) {
        Image(systemName: "photo")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this:

for dismiss, swipe down or tap on Back button! (I guarantee it is going dismiss)100%

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    @State private var showModalView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack
        {
            Button("showModalView") {showModalView.toggle()}
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModalView, content: {
            
            ZStack
            {
                Color.red
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                Button("← Back"){showModalView.toggle()}.foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
        })
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: well... thanks, but I would like to keep the popover instead of a sheet. Also, sheets don't seem to be dismissible by touching outside of it (didn't investigate much about it though). Nevertheless yes, sheets get dismissed automatically when the row of the List is removed.

Comment: "sheets don't seem to be dismissible by touching outside" they dismiss with right coding

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to move this logic into the containing view that has the list.

If your rows are very simple buttons as your code appears to be above, no need to put them in their own struct, and just use the button action to set an optional @State property that holds the image you want to present.

If you need the rows to be their own self contained views then just pass callback or use a @Binding, and on button tap, send the info you need back up the chain to the view containing the row (with the list) - and again present you popover from there.

When a row is removed from the list, you can now intercept that event and set your @State property back to nil (or dismiss your popover).

To ensure your popover anchors to the right place, what you could also do is leave the presentation of the popover in the row view as you have it now but also pass the image to show in that view, by setting a binding from the parent view.